# Order vs Degree of a Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm having difficulty distinguishing between the order of a group versus the degree of a group. It seems that they both mean the same thing, the number of elements within a group, except "order" is generalized for any group and "degree" refers to permutation groups. Is that correct?

Comment: The degree of a group of permutations of a finite set is the number of elements *in the finite set*, which is not the order of the group.    The degree of $S_n$, as the group of permutations of $\{1, \cdots, n\}$, is $n$ but its order is $n!$

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1405460/order-of-a-permutation-group-versus-degree-of-a-permutation-group).

Comment: Yes, isomorphic groups can have different degrees, or one can have a degree and the other not, but isomorphic groups have the same order. This means that "degree" is not a property of the group alone, but of its representation as a permutation group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, groups do not have a degree.   A subgroup of the symmetric group $S_n$ is called a *permutation group* of degree $n$.  And it does turn out that any group is isomorphic to a (possibly infinite)  permutation group (Cayley's theorem).

Otoh, the *order* of a group is just its cardinality (as a set).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you call "degree" of a finite group is its *minimal permutation representation degree*, namely the minimal degree of the permutation group it still embeds into.